# Responsive Collapse Menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The hamburger menu is not working with my code as is. All I have so far is the html document with link to Bootstrap 3.3.7 and links to jquery and link to my own css and my own javascript, but these contain nothing so far. What am I doing wrong? It was working just fine, and then it wasn't. Is it the order of the links, like Bootstrap link and or jquery links? am I missing a link? am I missing something in the navbar? I copied it straight from Bootstrap. I also want to add a sticky footer, but I am afraid to screw it up even further by adding more code.  I am a first time coder (still student in bootcamp) and just starting with Stackoverflow as well. Thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/script.js"></script>
    <title>Telefunken Score Keeper</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Telefunken ScoreKeeper</h1>
            <p>For the score-lovers.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I believe you are missing the `bootstrap.js` files https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: A few Bootstrap components require the JavaScript part of Bootstrap and collapsible is one of them. Also note you need jQuery (and `tether.js` in v4) loaded before `bootstrap.(min.)js`. Read more on `/getting-started` page of whatever version of Bootstrap you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include bootstrap JavaScript file

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/script.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <title>Telefunken Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>

     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img alt="Brand" src="...">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Telefunken ScoreKeeper</h1>
   <p>For the score-lovers.</p>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it!  I was missing the bootstrap javascript link.

I appreciate the help!